# How cobrowsing works?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, signalr

I am trying to create a cobrowsing in-browser JavaScript application from scratch. I am now dealing with sending data. I solved the communication between the two sides by using signalR, checking for changes on the side that sends the data using MutationObserver. The app basically works, I am able to send a complete html page and display it on the other side.

The main problem is that in order for it to work, the entire data has to be sent again every time something changes on the page, and that is not very ideal for the server.

I tried to create several html diffs but none of them work efficiently. Yes, I can detect the difference in percentages between pages without any problems, but I can no longer tell what exactly has changed on the page, or rather I can, but it is often very imprecise and it does not always include all changes.

I saved the old page (already "submitted" once) and compared it with the new page. I tried splitting the page into several blocks and then counting the changes in the blocks, I tried going through the whole page and comparing similar elements and determining which elements are new, changed or deleted. But all inaccurate!

I have already seen several very functional Cobrowsing applications (e.g. https://cobrowse.io/ ). That's why I ask how?

How to ensure a functional page comparison and not overload the server? Or do I have to have google servers? Or am I misunderstanding the whole thing and doing it wrong?

I will be glad for any help and opinion, Thanks

Comment: So ... you have no code to debug? That is, you havent even started yet?

Comment: Have you considered DOM diffing?  There's [a lot of prior art](https://www.google.com/search?q=DOM+diff) that does this.

Comment: @GetSet I can show you the diffs code, the others can't, because the codes "belong" to my organization. But still, rather trying to figure out how to even do such a part (optimizing data sending). The entire code is 3K+ lines long

Comment: "because the codes "belong" to my organization" ... how do you expect to get help here then? Concrete help that is versus opinions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks! I can try that. I try to avoid external libraries first (for licensing and management reasons). So I'm trying to do it all from scratch.

Comment: @GetSet "But still, rather trying to figure out how to even do such a part (optimizing data sending)." By that I mean that I don't want someone to debug my code here, but rather to introduce ideas on how to do comparison in html in js or overall cobrowsing in js.

Comment: *Am I misunderstanding the whole thing and doing it wrong?*  ... this is a good start point for conducting research. Perform an internet search of "cobrowsing algorithms". See what comes up to explore further. Also try "cobrowsing scholarly articles"

Comment: @GetSet I think you misunderstood my question. If you have nothing to add to the question. Thanks for joining the conversation

Comment: How to ask a question  ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask